# Drupal Login Issue after authentication using Simplesamlphp IDP

Tags: drupal, simplesamlphp

I have followed the steps mentioned on this below to integrate the Simplesamlphp with Drupal Application. But, I am facing the following issue after the successful authentication on External IDP.

https://www.drupal.org/project/simplesamlphp_auth

### Issue:  Drupal Login Issue after authentication using Simplesamlphp IDP

**Description**: When I click the federation link on on login block, it is redirecting to External IDP which i have configured correctly,

Then, after entering the credentials and it is authenticating correctly then it redirected back to Drupal application but its not creating a user on drupal site and not logging into drupal site.

### **Steps followed**

1. Installed the Drupal 7 : eg: local.mysite.com
2. Installed SimpleSAMLphp under drupal root folder - Eg: local.mysite.com/simplesaml
3. Configured SimpleSAMLphp as a Service Provider
4. Installed simplesamlphp_auth module on Drupal 7
5. Configured simplesamlphp_auth module
6. Activated the simplesamlphp_auth module
7. Federation link has been opened on login block and upon clicking the Link it is redirecting to External IDP provider then it asks to enter the credentials.
8. Upon entering the credentials, it is validating and authenticating.
9. Upon successful authentication it is redirecting back to Drupal application.

**10. But, its not creating a user on drupal site and not logging into drupal site**.

FYI: I have configured the session store.type = sql.

Have anyone faced similar issue and is there any solution for the same.
Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Regards,

Arun

Answer (score 0):

I am using it on Drupal 8, so not sure if it applies, but make sure you have "Register User" checked under User provisioning section on module configuration page. This setting is what helps create the account after authentication

[image]